# PHP -> PDO -> Prepare -> Call Procedure -> Insert Into -> Bind Parameters

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, prepared-statement, bindparam

using this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Insert_New_Return_Id`(IN Insert_Stmnt varchar(1000), OUT IDNum int)
BEGIN
    SET @buffer = Insert_Stmnt;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @buffer;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO IDNum;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

the following code works fine :

```
$statement=$con->prepare("CALL Insert_New_Return_Id (\"INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name)VALUES('test','test')\",@ID)");
$statement->execute();
$statement=$con->query("SELECT @ID");
while ($row = $statement->fetch()){echo "Last ID Insert : " . $row['@ID'];}
```

but when i'm trying to bind parameters the values are `?`

```
$first_name = "test";
$last_name = "test";    
$statement=$con->prepare("CALL Insert_New_Return_Id (\"INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name)VALUES('?','?')\",@ID)");
    $statement->bindParam(1, $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(2, $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement=$con->query("SELECT @ID");
    while ($row = $statement->fetch()){echo "Last ID Insert : " . $row['@ID'];}
```

If i try `VALUES(?,?)` returns an error.

How can i make this work? Call a procedure with prepare statement and binding parameters?

Thank you

Comment: Don't put parameters in quotes.

Comment: I also try VALUES(?,?) but returns an error.

Comment: DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Insert_New_Return_Id`
CREATE PROCEDURE `Insert_New_Return_Id`(IN Insert_Stmnt varchar(1000), OUT IDNum int)
BEGIN
    SET @buffer = Insert_Stmnt;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @buffer;
    EXECUTE stmt;
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO IDNum;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: procedure works fine

Comment: What error did you recieve? Paste it to your question

Comment: @HddnTHA Hope. Hope that error setting are set properly. ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge oh yes i hope too (:

Comment: i edit the question.. you can see the complete code

Comment: i know about '$con->lastInsertId();' and it's not correct to use it after execution of the statement.. when you have 1000+ users using the website you have to deal about milliseconds...

Answer (score 2):

```
$statement->bindParam(1, 'test', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(2, 'test', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

You must use a variable instead of the string 'test'. PDOStatement::bindParam binds variables by reference. By definition, you cannot do this with a string.
Use a variable instead.

```
$statement->bindParam(1, $str1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(2, $str2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Also, when you want to use `CALL` to call a stored procedure, just call the stored procedure by name. Do not repeat the query. Of course, this assumes you've done the work of adding the stored procedure to MySQL.

```
$statement=$con->prepare('CALL Insert_New_Return_Id(?,?)');
```

If you need a third parameter, add it to the stored procedure in MySQL and call it like this.

```
$statement=$con->prepare('CALL Insert_New_Return_Id(?,?,?)');
```

Comment: i can't use $statement=$con->prepare('CALL Insert_New_Return_Id(?,?)'); because in the () i have to write "INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name)VALUES(?,?)"

Comment: @GaLaTaS That must be a feature of MySQL I have never seen. If, possible, attempt to define the query down below inside of MySQL so that you can call the stored procedure from a single interface.

Comment: @RyanVincent Including strings?